# Removing Moen faucet spray head with stripped plastic slots

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I'm trying to replace the insert-type threadless aerator on my Moen kitchen faucet by removing the spray head, but the plastic slots on the spray head itself are pretty badly deformed and it seems like the methods discussed [in this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/228587/removing-moen-kitchen-faucet-aerator) won't work. I have [this tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CWM4PBX) but I can't find purchase on the stripped plastic. It seems to be on there really tight. The faucet and spray head are similar to the one in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14eimj38pqY).

Any ideas for how to remove the spray head when its plastic slots are in bad shape?

Answer (score 1):

You're removing the aerator to replace it. Further damage is inconsequential. Therefore, jam anything into the plastic that you can to get a purchase on it so it will turn.

You could use a flat-blade screwdriver or a pick or a pair of needle nose pliers. Anything at all that will give you a grip.

Of course, you'll want to use care and the proper tool when installing the new one because you don't want to damage that one. You might consider a little bit of grease on the new one to help prevent it from sticking, and, now that you've got the proper tool for installation, you'll use it anytime you need to remove the new aerator, so it's unlikely that you'll damage them in the future, so you won't run into this problem again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is with the spray head though- the aerator itself is an insert-type one without any threading that sits inside the spray head. Unfortunately the spray head is what is damaged; looks like I'll have to replace that too. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Providing actual pictures of _your_ setup, @Will would help anyone, but in this particular case, even without any additional detail, my advice is basically the same: Since you're replacing a part, whatever damage you may do to that part during removal is inconsequential since it's going in the bin. Just do what you need to in order to get the spray head off - if you damage it, you already have a perfectly good replacement in a box waiting to go on anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Moen has a lifetime warranty on its products. Yes I actually used it one on a 20+ year old kitchen faucet assembly and a new one that failed. I believe the number is: 1-800-465-6130, I simply called and they were some of the best I have ever worked with. You can go on line at "https://www.moen.com/professional/customer-support/contact-us", fill out the form and go there. They actually had the correct part and send instructions with pictures on how to repair the old one. I had it short order a day or so after the call.

Comment: This is great info, Gil! It sounds like the OP already has the replacement parts and just can't get the old ones off.

Comment: He should make the call there might be a nice surprise!